# identify unique users without authentication

Tags: php, mysql, security, apache, authentication

so my site has a feature that I intend to only allow to be used for a limited number of times per unique user...the thing is...I want to do this without having to force users to register and login to the site...

I was thinking of using IP addresses, but then IP addresses are easy to manipulate (with dynamic DNS, proxy servers etc)

So my question is, is there a method that is more reliable than using IP addresses for identifying unique users without forcing them to register

also I'm using the LAMP stack + JQuery so any solution that use them are welcomed...

Comment: What does dynamic DNS do with client IP manipulation?

Comment: woah, this even works with "private browsing" in chrome 16 c/o "lsoData mechanism".  Private browsing gets around all of the 12 other checks, but "lsoData mechanism" is retained.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These are evil, and your users will hate you, but here ya go:

http://samy.pl/evercookie/

Comment: +1 Although I would hate to find this deployed by any site I visited, it seems to answer the OP's question.

Comment: I understand why people might not want to have their usage tracked, but c'mon, I'm trying to do good here.  I'd like to use them in order to track user behavior and differentiate new users from existing users for the purpose of validating the idea that certain pieces of site functionality are getting a positive response (i. e. people are coming back and increased traffic isn't just from new users and marketing efforts).  Depending on what theory of morality you ascribe to, this should have a net positive impact on the community.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the server assign them an id on their first visit, save that in a cookie that never expires, and then have your site check for / use the cookie to authenticate on subsequent visits.

Comment: Since they aren't giving you any credentials, and user needs a unique key, just have the server hash the timestamp to get the key, or something similar.

Comment: And two simultaneous requests get the same hash. Neither of your proposed methods solve the OPs problem of reliable unique user identification.

Comment: So salt the hash with the IP to prevent collisions from simultaneous hits.  So long as you can get a unique key for each user, however you want to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Read about "super cookies", that might help a little more than just IPs and Cookies.
But if you want to restrict the access strictly your approach is not the right one.

Answer (score 0):

I've got easy access to [Firefox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox), [Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_%28web_browser%29), [konqueror](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konqueror), [opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29) (full-blown and mini), [surf](http://surf.suckless.org/screenshots/), [emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs/W3), [w3m](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3m), [links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konqueror), links2, [lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29), [elinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elinks), [epiphany](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphany_%28web_browser%29), and writing [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http) traffic by hand; I've got dozens of different HTTP proxies with different fingerprints;  [tor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_%28anonymity_network%29) and [ec2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_EC2) provide access to thousands of IPs and dozens of easily different [OS fingerprints](http://nmap.org/book/osdetect.html); presumably renting time on [botnets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botnet) is cheap these days.

How exactly would you know *me* from all this mess?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, cookies are the standard way to handle this (Google Analytics depends on them entirely), and they are easy to manipulate too (clear the cookies, go in and set "times_viewed" back to 0, etc.).  Fortunately, most people won't know how to do that.  I would advise you to encrypt your cookie content, but I still say cookies are the way to go here.

Comment: Additionally, I would keep in mind that super-secret-sensitive content should require a login.  Just accept the fact that some people will circumvent you.  Digital piracy is along the same vein...